# hstack csr matrix with pandas array

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am doing an exercise on Amazon Reviews, Below is the code.
Basically I am not able to add column (pandas array) to CSR Matrix which i got after applying BoW.
Even though the number of rows in both matrices matches i am not able to get through.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

#Create Connection to sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/609316120/Desktop/Python/Amazon_Review_Exercise/database/database.sqlite')

filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query("""select * from Reviews where Score != 3""", con)
def partition(x):
    if x < 3:
       return 'negative'
    return 'positive'

actualScore = filtered_data['Score']
actualScore.head()
positiveNegative = actualScore.map(partition)
positiveNegative.head(10)
filtered_data['Score'] = positiveNegative
filtered_data.head(1)
filtered_data.shape

display = pd.read_sql_query("""select * from Reviews where Score !=3 and Userid="AR5J8UI46CURR" ORDER BY PRODUCTID""", con)

sorted_data = filtered_data.sort_values('ProductId', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')

final=sorted_data.drop_duplicates(subset={"UserId","ProfileName","Time","Text"}, keep='first', inplace=False)

final.shape

display = pd.read_sql_query(""" select * from reviews where score != 3 and id=44737 or id = 64422 order by productid""", con)

final=final[final.HelpfulnessNumerator<=final.HelpfulnessDenominator]

final['Score'].value_counts()

count_vect = CountVectorizer()

final_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(final['Text'].values)

final_counts.shape

type(final_counts)

positive_negative = final['Score']

#Below is giving error
final_counts = hstack((final_counts,positive_negative))
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: I missed something so got error. But now the issue is after adding a column to csr_matrix my final shape is (364172,)
I am expecting (364171, 115282) . Below is the extension of above code

>>> final_counts.shape
(364171, 115281)
>>> type(final_counts)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
>>> positive_negative.shape
(364171,)
>>> type(positive_negative)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> final_counts = np.hstack((final_counts,positive_negative))
>>> final_counts.shape
(364172,)

Comment: `np.hstack`???  That's not the right `hstack` to use with a sparse matrix!.  It wraps the sparse matrix in an object dtype array with shape (1,).

Answer (score 3):

`sparse.hstack` combines the `coo` format matrices of the inputs into a new `coo` format matrix.

`final_counts` is a `csr` matrix, so the `sparse.coo_matrix(final_counts)` conversion is trivial.

`positive_negative` is a column of a DataFrame.  Look at

```
 sparse.coo_matrix(positive_negative)
```

It probably is a (1,n) sparse matrix.  But to combine it with `final_counts` it needs to be (1,n) shaped.

Try creating the sparse matrix, and transposing it:

```
sparse.hstack((final_counts, sparse.coo_matrix(positive_negative).T))
```

Comment: Tried merged_data = scipy.sparse.hstack((final_counts, scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(positive_negative).T))       But again error  TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int64'), dtype('O'))

Comment: Looks like your DataFrame has object dtype.  It successfully created the `coo_matrix`, but `sparse.hstack` can't create a new matrix from the mix of `int64` matrix and `O` matrix.  The `sparse` code doesn't have special provisions for object dtype,

Comment: So any other work around? My Final requirement is to add a column to the CSR Matrix from Pandas dataframe..

Comment: Can't you change the dtype?  Using the `astype` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
Used Below but still getting error

merged_data = scipy.sparse.hstack((final_counts, scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(positive_negative).T))

Below is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sparse' is not defined
>>> merged_data = scipy.sparse.hstack((final_counts, sparse.coo_matrix(positive_
negative).T))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sparse' is not defined
>>> merged_data = scipy.sparse.hstack((final_counts, scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(pos
itive_negative).T))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 464, in h
stack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 600, in b
mat
    dtype = upcast(*all_dtypes) if all_dtypes else None
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py", line 52, in upca
st
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int64'), dtype('O'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue with sparse matrices. you can convert the CSR matrix to dense by `todense()` and then you can use np.hstack((dataframe.values,converted_dense_matrix)). It will work fine. you can't deal with sparse matrices by using numpy.hstack
However for very large data set converting to dense matrix is not a good idea. In your case scipy hstack won't work because the data types are different in hstack(int,object). 
Try positive_negative = final['Score'].values and scipy.sparse.hstack it. if it doesn't work can you give me the output of your positive_negative.dtype