# Not able to use hstack on a Sparse CSR Matrix & Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

"final_counts" is of type "class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'" and of Shape (364171, 115281)

"new_column" is of type "class 'numpy.ndarray'" and of Shape (364171,)  Here I am not sure why the number of columns is null.

Using below code to add a new column "new_column" to "final_counts"

```
merged_data = scipy.sparse.hstack((final_counts, new_column))
```

Above Code is giving below error kindly help.

FYI - Same code on a very small data set is working.

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 464, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 585, in bmat
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 1, expected 364171.
```

Comment: `new_column` is a 1 dimensional array.  `(3,)` is a 1 element tuple.  Selecting a column from a 2d array, e.g. `x[:, 0]`, produces a 1 dimensional result.

Comment: This a spin off of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700979/hstack-csr-matrix-with-pandas-array